# Hibernate - map multiple foreign keys on same table

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one entity that have two foreign keys on the same table, for example:

```
class A {
    B _source;
    B _target;
}
class B {
    List<A> _as;
}
```

My question is how to map all "as" by source and target?
I'm using hibernate 4

Comment: Do you want to make class A contains a relation to itself like parent child?

Comment: No, class A represents relation between two B entities, and B entity need to have all his relations in one list. Only solution that I find is to split "as" list to "sources" and "targets".

Comment: Your structure is quite interesting, what you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: Nothing special, I just want from hibernate to do one fetch select with "or" for me instead two when I need all "as" for B entity and to avoid work with two lists of A entity.

Comment: It is still not clear to me.. Can you give your real use case in your question apart from your current implementation?

Comment: Real use case is that I have Profile entity, that can be CLUB or PLAYER, and Relation entity, that can be PLAYER is in CLUB's first team from 2008. PLAYER and CLUB both can be source or target in relation, depends on who created relation. So when I need to find all PLAYER's in my CLUB, I need to do query "SELECT FROM RELATION WHERE source = CLUB or target = CLUB" and I'm trying to find if hibernate can do that for me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot map all but you can achieve something like this:

```
public class A {
    @ManyToOne
    B _source;

    @ManyToOne
    B _target;
}

public class B {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "_source")
    List<A> sources;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "_target")
    List<A> targets;

    public List<A> getSources() {
        return sources;
    }

    public List<A> getTargets() {
        return targets;
    }

    public List<A> getAll() {
        return Stream.concat(getSources().stream(), getTargets().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

with the `getAll` method. (You may also need to apply `distinct` to that stream)

Comment: Yep, but I always need sources and targets together and they are lazy loaded so hibernate will always do two selects for them.